# Android Studio change Toolbar shadow color

Tags: android, android-layout, colors, toolbar

I need to change the color of the Toolbar's shadow on API 21 and above.

Is there is any function like `toolbar.setShadowColor(LIGHT_BLUE_COLOR)` or something.

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Answer (score 1):

try in your actionbar-->

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 yourActionBarid.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
 yourActionBarid.setElevation(0);
```

Note

Add getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY); before super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Comment: Activity crashed on your first line: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.shubham16.aiproject/com.shubham16.aiproject.MainActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content

Comment: Here is my code: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
        toolbar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        toolbar.setElevation(0);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: see my note....add Add getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY); before super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Comment: I commented above

Comment: you are getiing --> `Activity crashed on your first line: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.shubham16.aiproject/com.shubham16.aiproject.MainActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content` ?????

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {/*------------*/
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);/*------------*/
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);/*------------*/
        toolbar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));/*------------*/
        toolbar.setElevation(0);/*------------*/

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);/*------------*/
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);/*------------*/

Comment: thats what im saying again and again ....use this statement `getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);`  before oncreate method

Comment: Well, actually I put everything before super.onCreate. Now, it works fine but my problem isn't solve, I want to change the color of shadow to light blue color. Can you help.

Comment: then put your color blue ` actionbarid.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable("hexCOLORofblue"));

`

Comment: It changes the toolbar background color, not the shadow color.

Comment: what exactly you need?can you share output? or do you want to change notification bar color which is above toolbar?